# What's the name of this plant? And why the leaves become yellow?

Tags: identification, outdoor

What's the name of this plant grown in my yard? And why the leaves become yellow?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either bearded iris (Iris germanica or Iris pallida) or possibly a Flag iris (Iris versicolor) and is dying back for the winter if you're in the Northern Hemisphere. If you're in the Southern Hemisphere, then the dying leaves are either a sign of an insect problem - probably the Iris Borer if those are common in your location - or over-watering.

Comment: It is worth digging up the worst looking ones and check the rhizomes for borer like caterpillars. In IL I dug some iris to move them and found most had big borers although the plants did not look bad.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - definitely. I lost two large clumps to borers and had two more severely damaged last year. Dug out something like 30 borers and found maybe a dozen pupae in the surrounding soil (always a good idea to search through the surrounding 4-6" of soil looking for the pupae).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm in Northern Hemisphere and it is raining a lot these days, this may cause it over watered I think.